# PHP adding value to the textbox from another textbox before login

Tags: php

I would like to take passwordbox value and add it to login textbox after user clics submit
so that

```
(hidden field)Login:

Password:loginPassword

clicks submit->

(hidden)Login:login

Password:loginPassword
```

and our user has successfully logged in :)

```
<input id="username" name="username" class="inputbox" value="<?php echo $_POST['passwd'].Substring(0,5) ?>"/>
<input id="passwd" type="password" name="password" class="inputbox"/>
```

i'm kinda new to php..

Comment: Ummm.... so you're saying you have no usernames and people's usernames are actually the first 5 characters of their password? So why have a password field at all? Beyond that, your 'substring' is not php. That's javascript-ish code and outright illegal PHP syntax.

Comment: Wait, you want to capture the user's _password_ and render it to the page in *plain text*?  I have to ask... _Why_?

Comment: this is bad on so many levels, you should always have a username/email and password. the fact that the username is just the password but truncated makes having a username pointless. also why would you want to attempt to hide this using a hidden field? you can just view the source and see it.

Comment: @DavidNguyen well we have a standart login module in joomla, which has your belover login and password fields. What i whant to do is simply to hide login(ok i'll delete it, but just for David and Yuri, only for you guys), rename password to code, and create a "login" to secure pages using just the info from code(ex. pasw) field. The users will be added manually from admin panel. Probably I could rewrite the whole login module from the scratch and instead of modifying 3 words write 300...

Comment: so basically it is a password protected page but you are going to identify the user from a password? what if the passwords are the same? do you really want to complicate things on a proven model?

Comment: @DavidNguyen arghhh... ok you add a user to joomla : name:x; login:y; Password:y!@@#$1234234DSF-234234^&)~   ; then you try to add another user name:x;login:y(yes the same as an existing user);Password: y123234234@#$$xzc and here joomla throws an error message saying"Guess what user y already exists in db so you have to pic another login for him" . Proven model... jep I said the same thing to the client, but he's THE client and he thinks differently, so me and you are bouth wrong. Anyway my method would be a workaround to the proven model. +-

Comment: if this is the case, you really need to educate your customer. there has to be a way to uniquely identify the user whether it is a username or an email. the client is not ALWAYS right, this is a technical limitation the he/she needs to understand and is a security issue.

Comment: @DavidNguyen so what if this website has three users, their unique identifyers will be their Logins. Whats the difference if we create one paswfield:Login+Password and in codebehind separate them??? Still I will strongly suggest to the client to use SSL encryotion with RSA keys 4096bits and AES256bits and vpn'z we need max security for our cooking bolg!!! WTF if we dont have SSL'z anybody, even a 5 year old kid with wireshark could read your "secured" website (separated Login and Password )by catching packets in hotspot zone, so to be honest without ssl you don't have any security

Comment: Hey if you wanna do more work for no reason be my guest.

Comment: @DavidNguyen so how would you assign one textbox value to another?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you choose this kind of method to login.

Best practice is login with username and and passord.

Comment: the question was not about your opinion but about practical programming solution, which is 4 lines of code, now i have it, this question was a waiste of my time

Answer (score 0):

First. If your script uses password as the user name, then use password variable from `$_POST`, no need that useless manipulations. And also PHP is server-side language, so you can not do what you want w/o reloading the page. And so you've got two-steps authorization form? Which also not even logical? Again, why?!

Comment: joomla login module->change it using least amounts of code-> hide login field/delete it -> assign half of the pasw as login, and connect. Probably your'e suggestion would be to rewrite the whole module instead of modifying 2 words, interesting choise